# remove special characters from arabic string c#

Tags: c#

```
string text = textBox1.Text;

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

string my_String = (Regex.Replace(text, @"[\xd8\x80|[\xdb\xbf]|[\xdc\x80\\xdf\xbf]|[\xe0\xa0\x80\\xe0\xa3\xbf]|[^0-9a-zA-Z\._-]]", ""));
        textBox2.Text = my_String;
```

Comment: Hello AnthonyG, and welcome to StackOverflow. what problem are you experiencing? please describe what your issue and/or error(s) are in the question.

Comment: i am entering an arabic string in a textbox ... i wanna remove all special characters and type the arabic string alone without the special characters except the "-" ...

Comment: What isn't working? Please use the description part of your question to *describe* what is happening and what you have tried. Read [ask] for more guidelines

Comment: it isnt removing special characters

Comment: Ok u give us code but what is the question what is the problem ?

Comment: it isnt removing special characters from the arabic string how can i do that ?

Comment: please update your Question and add more information, what text do you get from `textBox1`, what should the result look like, what does the current result look like, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this.

```
string my_String = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0600-\u06FF]+", "");
```

This will match everything except arabic words (in range of `\u0600-\u06FF`). and replace them with `""`. I just noticed from comments that you dont need numbers so i removed it.

By special character what ever you mean dont put it in this pattern. so just put the things you want. other characters are considered special character.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [negative Unicode category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4) with a [named block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_12), this will leave just Arabic signs:

```
string myString = Regex.Replace(text, @"\P{IsArabic}", "");
```